# IF loop execution syntax generating infinite loop

Tags: if-statement

I have an if condition block which is running for infinity. Can someone explain me the behaviour? the block structure is:

```
   loop(ele:allelements){ if (flagTrue) { if (cond1) {...}
    if (cond2) {...}
    else { if(cond3) {...} }
     } }
```

This was a legacy code so dont ask me the justification of this labyrinth. I'm only concerned with the execution of infinite loop here.

If someone can kindly tell me.

Comment: I don't see a loop in there...

Comment: There is no loop here.....hence it can never go infinite.

Comment: This was in java. I have updated to include the loop over.

Answer (score 0):

From the given limited code. The only reason it will be an infinite loop is because value of `flagTrue` is not changed in the loop and always remain as `true`.

---

If this is for Java, your loop should be:

```
for (ele e :allelements){
  //... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes I agree , but then it should only run through allelements and not infinity. That's where I raised this question.

Comment: You should put that as a comment under my solution. With what was given, that only reason to make it infinite is the reason which I have stated.

Comment: You will not get anything more from anyone here unless you post your actual code. as anything could happen in your `(...)`.